# How to avoid a security warning in icedtea-web

Tags: java, icedtea

There is a site that I visit often, which has some buttons programmed in java (for no reason). There is a missing permission attribute, and so each time I enter the site, I receive this message
[image]

In fact, I receive one of those for each button. I am using icedtea-web 1.6.2 on **Arch Linux**. I tried to add an exception by writing the URL of this page in the file `$HOME/.java/deployment/security/exception.sites`, but it did not work, I still receive the message.

How can I do to stop receiving those messages? I use Firefox 50.1.0.

Comment: Run the Java Control Panel (`jcontrol`), select the Security tab, and add the site to the Exception Site List.  I’m not sure if that’s different than adding it directly to the file as you did, but there might be some small detail in the file’s format that’s easily overlooked.  Note that you only want to add the scheme and host, not the full URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For IcedTea-Web the Control Panel opens with `itweb-settings`. but the Secutiry tab do not have an exception list. There is a tab "Extended applet security" with a list, so I put there the URL with "Always trust" under "Unsigned applet Action", but it did nothing.

Comment: Ok, but with "Low security - All, even unsigned, applets will be run", the warning disappear. However, that is a global setting, and it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The original idea of AlejandroDC with extended appplet security is right. Unluckily, in 1.6 (current released) this went a bit bad. Although it is powerful, and it support regexes, some dialogs ignores it. It got fixed in 1.7 which should go out any soon.